# Fade animation for HTML details element with CSS

Tags: html, css, fade, html-tag-details

Using the HTML details element and its open-attribute we can build a fade in animation:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

details {
  margin: 20px;
}

summary {  
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-out;
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}

details[open] #content {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    Click me
  </summary>
  <div id="content">
    This is some content.
  </div>  
</details>
```

At least, this works fine in Firefox. In Chrome, the fade in animation only works randomly, like every 5th time or so. Most often the content just pops up without any animation.

**First question: Why is Chrome so buggy here?**

To build the fade out animation, a basic idea is to add to the `details:not([open])` selector. However, this does not work. It gives no animation at all.

**Second question: How to add a fade out animation with HTML and CSS alone?**

PS: I am aware how to build something like that with div's and JavaScript (or jQuery). The aim here is to build something with HTML details element and CSS alone.